# excel to access records with macro

Tags: database, excel, vba

not sure even where to start on this.  i have an excel workbook with tabs for different tracking sheets.  some for maintenance tracking and some for personnel work hours for different jobs.  it is very time consuming to pull, copy and paste the results i need and then compare them.  i already know that an access database would be a better product to use for tracking and pulling results together, however my boss always favors excel and does not want to get rid of the current products used by myself, the boss and a hand full of others in the office.  so i already know what needs to be converted to a database but have my hands tied for the time being.

so here is what i am trying to accomplish.  my boss has set up macros for several of the excel sheets to archive the days worth of results in maintenance and workers hours spent doing jobs.  what it currently does is, makes a copy of the sheet and saves that sheet to a network folder for us to look at if we have a problem and need to check results.  i would like to recode the macro to instead save those results to records in an access table.  some of the info is missing and would need to be created on the fly as the record is created.  because the sheet tracks only results for the day, there is no column in the excel sheet for the date.  so the date will have to be added to the record as it is created, which is usually yesterdays date.  results get fed into the excel sheet and stay until the next morning when we hit the archive macro button to save yesterdays results to an excel.xls file.

here is a screen shot of the sheet.
[dispatch log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6m3joi-ltLjZFFjSmI3ek9iYk0/edit?usp=sharing)

so when i try to bring all the days together i have to copy and paste from multiple xls files to one just to get the stats i need.  i know my way around access better then i do excel so this would be a great time saver for me.  if i could change the archive code to populate an access table would be great help.  anybody got any ideas?  thanks in advance for helping me.

code used to archive the excel sheet.

```
Sheets("DISPATCH LOG").Select
ActiveSheet.Copy
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

FileName = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")
On Error Resume Next
Kill "Y:\Dispatch_Archive" & FileName
On Error GoTo 0
WB.SaveAs FileName:="Y:\Dispatch_Archive\" & FileName

    'Delete the temporary file
WB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
WB.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: please edit your question to show what you've tried and what you're trying to accomplish that you haven't managed to yet.

Comment: i have been googlen this problem for about two months now.  the only reason i posted is because i havent found anything to help me yet.  isnt that what this is for?  ive searched for excel to access records, sql and so much more.  i still havent found how to do this.

Comment: Do you have any VBA knowledge at all ? Inserting Excel data in an Access database is a whole other story than just copying data from one sheet to another.

Comment: yes some vba, but just tinkering and googlen.  i have been pretty successful so far, just takes some pointing in the right direction.  and copying from sheet to sheet is what i hope to fix.

Comment: why do i get negative on this topic?  i already researched for a long period of time.  am i not descriptive enough on what i am asking for help on?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could link access to the workbooks as mentioned here

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-HA001219419.aspx

Kind of using the spreadsheets as four backend databases and then query and update them using the access front end

Comment: it will need to be imported because im dealing with an excel sheet for each day.  i am trying to make the macro just populate an access database table instead.  see i am not the one who uses this archive macro button.  a coworker uses this sheet and uses the macro.  i use the historical sheets that are created by the excel macro button.  so i would like my coworker to hit the button and populate an access database so that i can use the historical data.  thanks for your input.

Comment: Is it one sheet per workbook? Is it always the same number of columns?

Comment: one sheet gets saved from the original workbook each day which is what i have linked in the original post above.  the data i need to use is from A14 to P30ish.

Comment: I know, I want to know if it is one sheet per day in the same workbook or individual sheets in individual workbooks

Comment: 1 workbook, multi sheets used daily which creates multiple xls worksheets, one for each days archive or back-up data.

Comment: It wont be simple to control Access from inside Excel VBA. It's doable using Automation but not simple. You're best off changing the macro so that it writes to the same sheet for each type and just append rows to the sheet (adding an import date column for clarity) rather than making a new sheet.You can then link to the workbook on the network using the method in the answer